# Deductive reasoning & conditionals

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, philosophy-of-logic, deduction, logical-positivism

What would be a good example of explicit deductive reasoning that doesn't seem to be possibly interpreted correctly as a conditional (If A, then B)?

Comment: [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism).

Comment: @CanBeSaidClearly "Doesn't seem to be possibly" is an English phrase meaning "doesn't seem to be possibly". Don't think it could be expressed differently, I suspect it cannot, but prove me wrong if I am. If you did, you would prove that it is understandable. And if you don't, you confort my belief that it cannot be expressed differently. But no doubt it means something. I don't see how you could prove that this is not the case, since failing to understand something which is perfectly understandable is such a common occurrence.

Comment: You can help by articulating yours in more than one sentence.

Comment: @Fizz 1. The question isn't about the material implication. 2. I don't expect anyone to come up with any good example; I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Depending how much you want to stretch your argument, it would be interesting to hear from you how you argue that a bi-conditional (P if and only if Q) is expressible as a (single?) conditional (or I'm guessing you mean as a sequence of conditionals?). You need the "and" at the same meta-language level as the "if" for that to sound naturally.

Comment: @Conifold: Speakpigeon is actually arguing here that the (natural language) conditional encodes a consequence relation (at least in deductive contexts). So "A or B; not A, therefore B" is "translatable" into "If A or B and not A, then B".

Comment: N.B. the type of (natural langue) conditional you speak of here is sometimes called "consequential conditional".

Comment: Proof by "you can't prove me wrong" is quite an innovation

Comment: @Fizz 1. "*no single/unified [logica/formal] account of conditionals*".If that was a real problem, we wouldn't do anything at all ever because there is no single, unified account of anything. Observe that answers are routinely proposed on this website and others even though there is no unified account on anything. Simple, people reply according to their own account. - 2. "*you're going to argue*" I'm not here to argue, let alone convince anyone. I asked a question, if you cannot or don't want to answer, move on. My question is simple and perfectly understandable and i don't care for excuses.

Comment: @Fizz "*(P if and only if Q) is expressible as a (single?) conditional*" P ⇔ Q is not a single deductive reasoning, but the conjunction of two. So, yes, If P, then Q and if Q, then P.

Comment: @Conifold "* Speakpigeon is actually arguing*" I'm not arguing, I asked a question, and 
I try to reply to Fizz's comments.

Comment: @Fizz "*expressing something precise (like an "explicit deductive reasoning") in something less precise (conditionals in natural language, one reading of which is as "consequential conditionals")*" Fallacious. There is nothing somehow "less precise" about the conditional form. Further, if that was somehow lacking, people wouldn't do it, including mathematicians, and yet they all do it.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: mathematical proofs often don't need the distinction between language and meta-language... except when dealing with mathematical logic, i.e. when you're reasoning *about* statements that themselves have "ifs" in them. And in those contexts there's an effort to distinguish between language and meta-language by some work-level convention. (Most other mathematical domains indeed have no need to bother. E.g. there are no "ifs" in the object language of geometry. So any "if" in that context is obviously meta-linguistic without the authors having to specify.)

Comment: @Fizz 1. "*there's an effort to distinguish between language and meta-language*" Sure, but this is nothing special to formal logic. British Grammarians don't switch to French to discuss the grammar of English. 2."*there are no ''ifs'' in the object language of geometry*" But geometry is nothing without the logical relations between its axiomatic concepts and I'm not sure if there is even one theorem of geometry which is not a conditional. More generally, logical inference applies to any formalism, including any formal model of logic itself, correct or not. So, this is not a logical problem.

Comment: I can rephrase your claim "there is[n't] even one theorem of geometry which is not a conditional" as "there is[n't] even one theorem of geometry which is not a logical consequence [of geometry's axioms]". How does the word "conditional" shed any light on this matter at mathematical level? I'd say the answer is that it doesn't. Your only claim is that in natural language we can use "consequential" conditionals to express logical consequence and be understood properly in most contexts. Again, I don't see the big deal here.

Answer (score 6):

It would be worthwhile distinguishing between a conditional sentence in the object language and a conditional in the metalanguage. Some deductive arguments have a conditional in the object language, e.g. those of the form modus ponens or modus tollens. Some arguments do not, e.g. those of the form conjunction elimination, disjunction elimination, etc.

But what is always possible (and I think this is what your question is asking) is that a deductive argument can be expressed as a kind of modal conditional at the meta level. A valid argument is one such that *necessarily* **if** all the premises are true **then** the conclusion is true.

The modal term 'necessarily' can be replaced by some other modality or generality, depending on what account of validity you find most congenial. Some common ones are: under all interpretations, under all substitutions of the non-logical constants, under all permutations of the domain of quantification, in all possible worlds, it is a priori knowable that, it is provable that, it is conceptually certain that, or whatever.

Comment: 1. "*distinguishing between*" I don't see the need for this distinction. You would need to give an example proving I am wrong. Rules such as "conjunction elimination" are perfectly understandable in everyday English. As I see it, mathematical logic is not logic but it is logical.2. "*modal conditional at the meta level*" No, no extraneous notion of modality is implied in my question. Just the ordinary conditional.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: it's necessary (to make the distinction) if you want to reason about proofs as mathematical objects themselves. See [sequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent) and [proof theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/). Also, the whole programme of [abstract algebraic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/) is built upon abstracting the notion of consequence relation to its properties.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Also, in logics besides the classical one are often not structurally complete. So one needs to distinguish derived rules (i.e. rules provable in the logic itself) and admissible rules which can be added to the logic whiteout changing provable tautologies . Again, you cannot make this distinction unless you have a notion of sequent. Since you tagged this modal logic: in that context, an example of admissible but non-derivable rule is "the rule of necessitation". If this is unclear, as a Q separately... although some like have been asked here before.

Comment: @Fizz "*it's necessary (to make the distinction) if you want to reason about proofs as mathematical objects themselves*" Not at all. My question is about deductive reasoning and the natural language conditional. The logic of deductive reasoning is definitely sturdy enough to accommodate reasoning with metalevels.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: ok, see the 2nd part of my answer then which exemplifies the difficulties of expressing both logical and meta-logical "ifs" by the same word.

Comment: @Fizz "*see the 2nd part of my answer*" I broadly understand what you mean, but my point is that this has nothing to do with logic.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: that's just your opinion, stated as a fiat/fact. In your previous comment above you said "My question is about deductive reasoning and the natural language conditional." Clearly you link logic and language. Then you say that language has nothing to do with logic. A contradiction. See also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/73775/deductive-reasoning-conditionals/73778?noredirect=1#comment224865_73775

Comment: @Fizz "*you say that language has nothing to do with logic. A contradiction*" Fallacious. I didn't say that. My question is about the relation between natural-language conditionals and logic, and that does not imply that problems of language are problems of logic.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: ok, so when you said "this has nothing to do with logic" what does "this" refer to? Please state that without anaphora so we can have a meaningful conversation.

Comment: @Fizz By "this" I meant your whole point about metalevels. I thought this much was clear. We are not having a meaningful conversation, I have to reply to your comments when you introduce confusion into my question. This is supposed to be a philosophy forum, and all the answers I get are from mathematicians who don't have clue how logic works but think they do because they've learnt mathematical logic. All you can do is regurgitate mathematical logic. I don't care for that. Mathematical logic is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for objections to characterizing natural language conditionals with the material conditional ("->"). If so, two examples come to mind.

First, from Van McGee:

> (1) If that creature is a ﬁsh, then if it has lungs, it is a lungﬁsh 
> (2) That creature is a ﬁsh 
> (3) Hence, if it has lungs, it is a lungﬁsh

If we treat "if...then" in natural language as the material conditional, then we have:

> (1*) A -> (B -> C) 
> (2*) A 
> (3*) B -> C

Van McGee claimed, however, that while (1*) and (2*) might be stipulated to entail (3*), one can construct scenarios in which (1) and (2) are true, but (3) false.

Second, natural language counterfactuals raise similar problems for material conditionals:

> (4) If Hoover had been born in Russia, he would've been a communist 
> (5) If Hoover were a communist, he would've been a traitor 
> (6) Hence, if Hoover had been born in Russia, he would've been a traitor

Which - if using the material conditional to model - results in:

> (4*) A -> B  
> (5*) B -> C 
> (6*) A -> C

But while (4*) and (5*) entail (6*), many believe (4) and (5) can be true while (6) false.

Comment: 1. My question isn't about the material conditional. 2. In your "McGee" example, the implication (A → (B → C)) ∧ A ⊢ B → C is a simple modus ponens and we don't need the material implication to see that it is a logical truth. McGee's counterexamples are fallacious. 3. "*counterfactuals raise similar problems*" Counterfactuals do falsify the material implication, but the two arguments have the same form and are true. If the conclusion is false, then at least one of the premises is false, irrespective of what "*many believe*". McGee's claims are fallacious.

Comment: I suspect Van McGee's argument would be that in natural language the statement "if it has lungs, it is a lungfish" can be interpreted as a general statement about all things with lungs (including non-fish things), as opposed to some specific named object in your domain of discourse that the previous propositions were also specifically referring to (and which was established to be a fish by proposition 2). So it'd be an illustration of semantic ambiguity in if-then statements of natural language.

Comment: @Hypnosifl No, no semantic ambiguity here. and we don't need to call on the notion of domain. Logic is 100% about form. McGee's natural language argument is perfectly valid irrespective of domain. Replace by A's and B's, and this is still valid. Aristotle did that 2,500 years ago, why are we now going backward? McGee's fallacy is precisely not to respect the form of the argument. One can always equivocate and there is nothing to stop McGee doing that.

Comment: There is semantic ambiguity in what logical form you assign each statement, how you "translate" informal English into a formal logic statement. If "that creature" is referred to with the individual constant t, then statement #1 could be translated as Fish(t) -> (Lungs(t) -> Lungfish(t)) and statement #2 could be translated as Fish(t). But statement #3 does not refer to "that creature" so it could be translated as "For all x, Lungs(x) -> Lungfish(x)". And in this translation, the third statement would not follow deductively from the first two in first-order logic.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*There is semantic ambiguity in what logical form you assign each statement*" There is no semantic in the operation of translating. There may be semantic ambiguity in the original and in the result. A translation is not ambiguous by itself. It may be acceptable or not acceptable, and possibly consistent or not consistent. The problem with McGee's example is perfectly obvious. This is a gross fallacy. He is essentially arguing on the basis of the ambiguities of informal arguments that the logic of formal arguments doesn't work. He is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Given your other comments on this page, you identify the conditional with the consequence relation (at least in this context of deductive reasoning). This is fine in classical logic because it has a/the deduction theorem and is also structurally complete (meaning every [admissible rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule) is also derivable in classical logic). So, sure in classical logic

A, B |- C iff
 A |- B->C iff
|- (A /\ B) -> C (and even) iff 
   |- A -> (B->C)

And likewise

A->B, A |- B iff
 |- ((A->B) /\ A) -> B iff
 |- (A->B)->(A->B)

Because classical logic can be axiomatized just based on the material conditional (and modus ponens), one can claim there's no need for any connective besides the [material] conditional (and either negation or a false element) in classical logic. (More precisely the implication-negation fragment [is functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Minimal_functionally_complete_operator_sets) in propositional classical logic.)

In general though, in other logics, it's not safe to make this identification of the conditional with the consequence relation. Even intuitionistic logic [admits](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2694922) rules that are not derivable in the logic itself.
So if your "explicit deductive reasoning" allows any logic besides the classical one, you cannot make this claim that the conditional and the consequence relation are one and the same notion.

---

If (on the other hand) your "explicit deductive reasoning" refers to some natural language statement encoding a modus ponens (for instance), I don't see how it's possible to intelligibly express it *just* using consequential conditionals and not sound gibberish in natural language. For instance, what is your proposed re-encoding of this explicit reasoning:

> **If it rains, [then] the soil gets wet. It rains. Therefore the soil gets wet.**

using just if-thens? Are you claiming that one can be easily understood if instead of the above one says:

> If if it rains then the soil gets wet and it rains, then the soil gets wet.

I'm fairly sure you don't mean that. You're perhaps thinking that just "If it rains, then the soil gets wet" is the whole act of "explicit deductive reasoning", but the latter shortened version is actually not *explicit* about the fact that it rains.

Sure you can sound less gibberish by using something else than "if-then" for the inner conditional here

> Assuming (or knowing) that whenever it rains the soil gets wet, then if it rains, then [surely] the soil gets wet.

While more comprehensible (because I've avoided repeating "ifs" by substituting a "whenever" for one of them), this latter form sounds like we're just repeating a hypothetical than concluding anything about what's going on right now. But in the "double if" sentence, this doesn't help much with getting a comprehensible form:

> If whenever it rains the soil gets wet and it rains [right now], then the soil gets wet [right now].

... unless you add some helper words (like "right now") to hint at the distinction between stating a consequence (as a conditional) and applying it to some facts. (And even then it's barely comprehensible.) Which gets exactly to the point that there's a need to disambiguate the level/kinds of these two "ifs" in an "explicit deductive reasoning" like MP.

To make this last part a bit more precise (and perhaps more clear/intuitive), if you consider the Curry Howard correspondence, in which MP corresponds to function application, you're basically confusing a function with an application of it. (Before you protest that the Curry Howard correspondence only deals with intuitionistic logic--that is true, but not relevant for *your* confusion. In order to deal with classical logic under the Curry Howard correspondence, you need to additionally consider multi-conclusion sequents like A |- B, C which are intuitionistically impermissible, but in classical logic they are interpreted as A |- B \/ C. This requires an [extended](https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/%7Epdownen/publications/cdsc.pdf) lambda calculus (e.g. the lambda-mu-mu calculus) in which a "co-term" can non-deterministically output "whatever it wants" from a disjunctive sequent.)